# Get the Cursor Position in tinymce using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

How to find the Cursor position from tinymce without using bookmark.Give any suggestion for get the cursor position

Comment: Had a similar issue.

Have a look at this SO-Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382571/how-can-i-get-the-cursor-line-number-of-a-contenteditable-html-element

Comment: that link is not working, i got output was Nan 'Not an number'

Comment: it works, you will have to tweak the code to your needs